# curry function syntax in swift

Tags: swift, functional-programming, closures

I was going through this [blog](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introduction-to-function-currying-in-swift). When I tried write curry function on my own method:

```
func stdCurry(f : (A,B) -> C) -> (A)->(B->C) {
    return { (a:A) ->(B -> C) in  {
            (b:B) -> C in
            {
                return f(a,b)
            }
        
        }
        
    }
}
```

I got an error:

> :7:22: error: declared closure result 'C' is incompatible with contextual type '_'
> (b:B) -> C in
> ^
> _

But when I remove the flower parentheses around trailing closure then it won't report any error. Can anybody help me to understand this.

Comment: That is because, you try to introduce yet another block by those extraneous flower braces after '(b:B -> C in' Actually you want in this case only 2 closures nested, if you introduce those flowery braces, you end up with 3 closures and not 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner curly braces `-> in { ... }` tells swift that this inner part is a closure, whereas it in fact only contains a value (the `C` type evaluation of `f(a,b)`). If you remove these inner curly braces, your example work.

E.g., try

```
func stdCurry<A,B,C>(f : (A,B) -> C) -> (A) -> (B -> C) {
    return { (a:A) -> (B -> C) in  {
        (b:B) -> C in
        return f(a,b) // <-- this is not a closure (just returns a value of type C`
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've added the generic types to the function signature above (perhaps you function is part of a class and you get your types `A`, `B` and `C` from there).

To make the error above more clear, consider this a bit simpler example (taking a closure and returning it):

```
/* This is ok */
func myClosure<A,B>(f: (A) -> B) -> (A) -> B {
    return {
    x in f(x)
    }
}

/* Error: return type here is not (A) -> B, but contains
   an anonymous closure () -> B */
func myClosure<A,B>(f: (A) -> B) -> (A) -> B {
    return {
        x in { f (x) }
    }
}

/* Ok */
func myClosure<A,B>(f: (A) -> B) -> (A) -> (() -> B) {
    return {
        x in { f(x) }
    }
}
```

---

Also note that since Swift knows (infers)---from your function signature---the types in as well as what type/closure to expect in return for each `in ...` statment, you can omit the closure type (`(a:A) -> (B -> C)`) as well as the `return` keyword and make your expression more compact as follows:

```
func stdCurry<A, B, C>(f: (A, B) -> C) -> A -> (B -> C) {
    return { a in { b in f(a, b) } }
}
```

---

At your request in the comments below: you can make use of *"multiple statements"* in the tail e.g. by using the approach of the third "simple example" above, e.g.:

```
func stdCurry<A,B,C>(f : (A,B) -> C) -> (A) -> (B) -> () -> C {
    return { (a:A) -> (B -> () -> C) in  {
        (b:B) -> () -> C in
        return {
            // ...
            f(a,b)
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that as the function signature grows somewhat "messy", it's favourable to omit these details in the actual closures of your function, i.e.:

```
func stdCurry<A,B,C>(f : (A,B) -> C) -> (A) -> (B) -> () -> C {
    return { a in  {
        b in
        return {
            // ...
            f(a,b)
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, one more query. If there is multiple statement in tail what should I do?

Comment: @Raviprakash Happy to help. You could possibly use an anonymous closure in return type (`() -> B`), see the third "simple example" in my edit above.